# Generate Report Using Report Viewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010

I want to display report in my admin panel when I select the sales person from dropdown list in my page but nothing is displayed and display some error here.

Below is my code:

```
protected void BtnViewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/SalesPerson.rdlc");
    DataSet ds = GetData("select * from customer_new where salesperson in (select +
    email from Registration where name='" + ddsalesperson.SelectedValue.ToString() + 
    "')");
    ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("customer_new",ds.Tables[0]);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
}
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
           {
                  sda.Fill(ds, "customer_new");
                  return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the following error :

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source
>   'DataSet1'.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the dataset "DataSet1" has not recieved data. I'd take a guess that the dataset "customer_new" doesn't actually exist, or if it does you have 2 datasets, one of which you may or may not be using.
Try:

```
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",ds.Tables[0]);
```